# Potential difference in 3 dimensional circuit junctions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, potential, capacitance

I came across the following circuit where capacitors of equal capacitance are arranged on every edge of a cube:

[image: I named some junctions with alphabets other than A and B]

I'm trying to find the net capacitance between A and B so I calculated the potential difference between A and B by assuming charge from positive terminal A gets distributed equally between arms AC, AH and AF, so on and vice versa from the negative terminal B.

Since the potential difference between junctions AC, AH and AF (same goes for CD,CE; HE,HD; and FE,FG...etc) are equal due to symmetry, it becomes easy to consider one of the paths between A and B as summing up to give the net potential difference: $$V_{A-B}= V_{A-C} + V_{C-D} + V_{D-B}$$

What if this weren't the case, when the capacitors are of unequal capacitance and thus edges of common vertices have unequal potential differences with respect to each other? Since that means $V_{A-B}$ will vary depending on which path (edges that are connecting A and B) you choose, should you consider the path which gives you the highest difference in potential? Because it would make sense if higher potential implies a stronger flowing current through that particular path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$V_{AB}$ will still be path-independent, this is required by Kirchhoff's voltage law. $V_{AB} = V_{AC} + V_{CD} + V_{DB}$ is still valid, and so is $V_{AB} = V_{AH} + V_{HD} + V_{DB}$, even though it may be that $V_{AC} \ne V_{AH}$, etc.

As for how to calculate the equivalent capacitance, I don't think there is an easy way. You can solve this through a series of judicious applications of the [Y-Δ transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform#Basic_Y-%CE%94_transformation), which leads to capacitors in series or parallel that you can then combine. That way you won't have to solve any equations, but that doesn't mean the expressions you will be manipulating won't be cumbersome (unless you plug in some numbers and are not trying to come up with a general expression valid for any set of capacitances). In the equations on the Wikipedia page, you need to replace resistances $R$ by inverse capacitances $C^{-1}$.

A more general approach is to apply [Kirchhoff's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws) and solve the resulting equations. The common way to do this systematically is [nodal analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodal_analysis). Call node $A$ ground (i.e. $V_A = 0$), call the voltage of node $B$ $V$, and assign voltages to each of the other vertices. By doing this, you immediately satisfy Kirchhoff's voltage law.

Kirchhoff's current law is applied as follows. At every node besides $A$ and $B$, use the fact that the charges on the capacitor plates connected to that node add to zero:
$$C_{CA}V_C + C_{CE}(V_C - V_E) + C_{CD}(V_C - V_D) = 0$$
$$C_{HA}V_H + C_{HD}(V_H - V_D) + C_{HG}(V_H - V_G) = 0$$
$$C_{IA}V_I + C_{IG}(V_I - V_G) + C_{IE}(V_I - V_E) = 0$$
$$C_{EB}(V_C - V) + C_{EI}(V_E - V_I) + C_{EC}(V_E - V_C) = 0$$
$$C_{DB}(V_D - V) + C_{DC}(V_D - V_C) + C_{DH}(V_D - V_H) = 0$$
$$C_{GB}(V_G - V) + C_{GH}(V_G - V_H) + C_{GI}(V_G - V_I) = 0$$

This is a linear system of 6 equations with 6 unknowns (treat $V$ as a known number). After solving the system, you calculate the equivalent capacitance as $Q/V$, where $Q$ is the total charge on the capacitors connected to $B$:
$$C_\text{eq} = \frac 1 V \left[C_{BE}(V - V_E) + C_{BG}(V - V_G) + C_{BD}(V - V_D)\right]$$
or alternatively, you can use the negative of the charge on $A$:
$$C_\text{eq} = \frac 1 V \left(C_{CA}V_C + C_{HA}V_H + C_{IA}V_I\right)$$

You can set $V$ to $1$ to simplify things slightly. You would normally throw this kind of problem at a computer instead of solving it by hand.